Intervalometer for video on Panasonic G3?
I need to record video for longer than the allotted 30 minute limit.  I am using an old Panasonic DMC-G3.
Does an intervalometer work with the G3, specifically for video?  I read that this could work with other camera's if the shutter button function was switched to video, where the intervalometer could restart after the specified interval.  I have been through the G3 manual and I don't think the shutter button can be switched.
Does anyone have any idea's or point me in the right direction?
